# How to get data from database one day previous on click

Tags: java, spring-boot, hql

I'm building my app. I want to get documents from the DB when I clicked button 'previous'. Then the documents from the previous day should be displayed (e.g. 11 documents). When I click the button again, documents from two days ago should be displayed (e.g. 5 documents). And when I click the button again, documents from three days ago should be displayed (e.g. 8 documents), etc. etc.

I have a method getting documents from the current day, but I don't know how to make each click move the date back one day and get documents.

uztId is user ID from DB.

dateOfIssue is Data type.

My local date is "dd.MM.yyyy"

Controller:

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/getDocsPrevDay/{uztId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
@ApiOperation(value = "Get documents previous day and again")
@ApiResponses({
        @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Success", response = ResponseApi.class)
})
public List<Documents> getPrevDay(@PathVariable("uztId") Integer uztId) {
    return documentsDao.getPrevDay(uztId);
}
```

DAO:

```java
private static final long ONE_DAY_MILLI_SECONDS = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
private static final String DATE_FORMAT = "dd.MM.yyyy";

public List<Documents> getPrevDay(Integer uztId) {
    java.util.Date currentDate = new java.util.Date();
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);

    long previousDayMilliSeconds = currentDate.getTime() - ONE_DAY_MILLI_SECONDS;
    java.util.Date previousDate = new Date(previousDayMilliSeconds);
    String previousDateStr = dateFormat.format(previousDate);

    System.out.println("current date: " + dateFormat.format(currentDate));
    System.out.println("previous: " + previousDateStr);

    List<Documents> dokumentsPrevious = (List<Documents>) getCurrentSession()
            .createQuery("from Documents where uztId = :uztId and dateOfIssue = current_date()")
            .setParameter("uztId", uztId)
            .getResultList();

    return dokumentsPrevious;
}
```

Comment: Your UI model should track either the date, or the number of days previously, and communicate either the date, or the number of days ago you want to retrieve. So if you display records from 2023-05-04, the previous button will send a request for documents of 2023-05-03, etc, etc.

Comment: As an aside, your query currently retrieves documents from the current date, always. Also, stop using `java.util.Date` and switch to using things like `java.time.LocalDate`.

Comment: OK, but my method get only documents from current day. Do you know what should I do to display documents from 04.05.2023, then 03.05.2023 etc...?

Comment: When I change the query to:
```
"from Documents where uztId = :uztId and dateOfIssue = " + previousDateStr;
```
then I have an error: [ERROR] ErrorTracker - line 1:103: unexpected token: .2023

Comment: That's possibly a problem with the date format. You replaced the `current_date()` database function call by a date with a custom (German?) format. That may cause the *unexpected token: .2023*. You could run `current_date()` in the database and output it, then have a look at the format. My first try without would be an ISO date: `2023-05-04`, you can calculate it by `previousDateStr = java.time.LocalDate.now().minusDays(1).format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE);`

Comment: You shouldn't concatenate values into a query string, you should use parameters for that.

Answer (score 1):

I was resolve my problem.

Have a nice day.

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getPrevDay/{uztId}/{daysOffset}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
@ApiOperation(value = "Każdy klik wyświetla dokumenty z pobranego dnia - 1")
@ApiResponses({
    @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Success", response = ResponseApi.class)
})
public List<Documents> getPrevDay(@PathVariable("uztId") Integer uztId,@PathVariable Integer daysOffset) {
    return documentsDao.getPrevDay(uztId, daysOffset);
}
```

DAO:

```
public List<Documents> getPrevDay(Integer uztId, Integer daysOffset) {

    ZoneId defaultZoneId = ZoneId.systemDefault();
    LocalDate myVariable= LocalDate.now();
    myVariable= myVariable.plusDays(daysOffset);
    Date prevDay = Date.from(myVariable.atStartOfDay(defaultZoneId).toInstant());

    List<Documents> dokumentsPrevious = (List<Documents>) getCurrentSession()
        .createQuery("from Documents where uztId = :uztId and dataOfIssue = :dateOfIssue order by dateOfIssue DESC")
        .setParameter("uztId", uztId)
        .setParameter("dateOfIssue ", prevDay)
        .getResultList();

    return dokumentsPrevious;
}
```